# Allocating pointers inside an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, allocation

OK, so the problem is basically like the title. Couldn't find a question that got all bits of it, so I figured I'd ask.

Say I want an array of structs shaped like the following

```
typedef struct s_woo{
    char** n;
    char* x;
} t_woo;
```

So I believe I should do

```
t_woo* woos = malloc(num_woos * sizeof(*woos));
```

Seems simple enough (and should deter people from yelling at me for my habit of casting malloc).

Then I want to initialize the things in each of those structs.

So intuitively I do:

```
for(i = 0; i < num_woos; i++){

    num_ns = randomint1 / randomint2; //let's say num_ns is big, like 250-ish, average, and changes every round of the loop

    woos[i].n = malloc(num_ns * sizeof(char*));
    woos[i].x = malloc(num_ns * sizeof(char));
    for(j = 0; j < num_ns; j++){
        woos[i].n[j] = malloc(16 * sizeof(char)); // I just want 16 characters per char*
    }
}
```

This is the boiled down version of what I have in my code. I want to know what can possibly go wrong with what I've written - like any possible thing. I'm not looking for anything in particular, just general problems with the above, like memory/heap issues, pointer mistakes etc.

Leave out "Virtual Memory Exhausted". My code error checks for that using a wrapper function on malloc, so I'm very sure that's not it.

Comment: Looks fine from here. It would help avoid coding errors to use a define/constant instead of `16`. I don't know if you intend to store strings in these arrays but if so, don't forget about the null terminator.

Comment: If you're going for robust design you could use a bit more *encapsulation*, i.e. turn `t_woo` into a self-contained object. This would involve putting `num_ns` insde `t_woo`, and having a function which does all the construction for a single `t_woo` (and another one that does the destruction later). Then you loop through your list of `t_woo`'s calling the construction function on each one, as soon as possible after you allocate the memory for them.

Comment: `and changes every round of the loop`.. Are you deallocating memory before allocating in each round of loop? Maybe your outside loop runs so many times, that it gives a memory error.

Comment: You didn't store `num_ns` anywhere!

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I may do just that with the encapsulation. This works in C?

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay I don't deallocate at all - could you elaborate further? This loop is meant to "setup" the pointers. Can you think of a way the outside loop would give a memory error? Oh, some further information - the loop I have breaks on the SECOND malloc, so `woos[i].x`. It's fine on the first, but on the second, something goes wrong. Furthermore, it does this no matter how small num_ns is; I can make num_ns = 2 for every round and it'll break. Of course, it may not be any of this code that breaks it, I just wanted to make sure I'm doing this part correctly.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you, encapsulation was a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Even better:

```
 static const size_t woo_n_size = 16; 
  /* To make sure you use 16 everywhere,
   * also easier to change it
   */

 struct woo_item {
     char n[woo_n_size];
     char x;
 };

 struct s_woo {
     struct woo_item *items;
     size_t size; / * optinal, to keep track of item count */ 
 }
```

With the `woo_item` struct you can make sure there is no `x` without `n[woo_n_size]` allocated, and vice versa.
You can remember the count of woo_items by having a designated null element to close each of your lists, or just store a `size` member in `s_woo`